# Mongoose : Types referring to other models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

I've this:

models/record.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var RecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   address : require("./address").Address
});
var Record = mongoose.model('Record', RecordSchema);
module.exports = {
   Record: Record
}
```

models/address.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    streetLine1: String,
    streetLine2: String,
    city: String,
    stateOrCounty: String,
    postCode: String,
    country: require("./country").Country
});
var Address = mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema);
module.exports = {
  Address: Address
}
```

models/country.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var CountrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   areaCode: Number
});
var Country = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
module.exports = {
   Country: Country
}
```

It's actually showing this error:

TypeError: Undefined type `Model` at `country`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

I am trying to create a model where few types is another model. How to archive this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are exporting a model from country.js and using the same by requiring in the address schema creation. While creating nested schemas, the value for a property should be a schema Object and not a model.

Change your country.js to:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var CountrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   areaCode: Number
});
module.exports = {
   Country: CountrySchema
}
```